# Sending safely JSON to server via an HTML form page

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have an html page that has a form and is communicating to a server via JSON requests, when loading (e.g. in order to remember user's previous answers) and when submit button is pressed (e.g. in order to save his new answers). Every user has a specific user_id that is located as an attribute in the url of the website. I have only HTML pages, CSS and Javascript that makes some simple functions, as well as received and sends the requests.

The problem is that the server needs an *api-key* for the request to happen, that I need to be kept hidden, but instead is easily discovered when the user sees the source code. I want this specific line to be hidden, but I guess this is not possible without any backend in the game.

I would like to know the easiest and fastest way to get from this state (just frontend, where every piece of information in the source code is totally insecure)  to another where the api-key (at least) is not on the open.

I guess the solution is to use a server for that part but I need suggestion on the easiest transition from my code to another. I tried to use GWT, as I am a bit more familiar with JAVA backend application (but not with GWT), but seems like a big trouble, where I need to change my HTML, my Javascript and also the CSS that I have may not be useful, as well as I face a lot of problems when trying to read my parameters.

I know that it is not the best way but I do not have a lot of time to make it work, so sorry if it seems lazy (I am new to this type of programming), but I haven't found anything helpful and I cannot study for 2 weeks in order to be able to begin implementing it.

Is node.js (which is Javascript and I already have implemented the request sending/receiving in this language) easier than GWT for that matter? Will my sensitive data be secure in that way? I would be grateful if there was a similar sample, that I could start using for my implementation, as I haven't find anything that is specifically helpful for my situation.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess your solution is to make your backend the call to the api. So you basically need to create a web service endpoint on your backend, that way you could send your data from javascript to your server through this endpoint, and it will use the key and keep it hidden from any clients.

Comment: GWT is pretty much dead, stay away.

Comment: @robinvrd the question is a bit convoluted but I think the issue is that OP has realised this, but is basically asking us "what is the easiest server-side language to learn in a day or two". Which is not the kind of primarily-opinion-based question we normally answer.

Comment: Oh alright, so typically, the best way to build the fastest backend is the way you know the best. If you do not have any knowledge in backend maybe using PHP is the fastest way as you do not need any dedicated server out there to use it.

Comment: @Nik ... "I guess the solution is to use a server for that part" Yes that's the solution. Your page sends a request to your server, and your server sends a request to the API, using the api-key and the data received from the page. The server can keep the key safe and invisible to users. But we don't do recommendations on which product to use. What I will say is that if you already know JavaScript (and that's all you know) then yes NodeJS might be an easier transition than some others. But mainly it's the conceptual stuff you'd need to get your head around as much as anything.

Comment: P.S. If you don't fancy Node, then PHP can be ok for beginners as it's quite relaxed about how you do things, but  equally that same fact means it's also very easy to make a huge nasty mess if you're not careful. And of course once you've made a language choice then these days, unless you're just planning to implement something super-simple to do this one job, then you generally want to think about choosing a framework to go on top of it, so that services such as URL routing, error handling, some security is already built and easier to implement quickly.

Comment: @robinvrd, thanks very much for the answer! You mean sending the JSON file to my backend and after that I should send it to the server, right? And as I do not have any backend for this purpose yet, what would you suggest for that purpose? I mean I need something that will work easily, with plenty of information/tutorials as to how can I do it (as GWT was a bit of pain in the ass, at least for me, even at the simplest cases, like reading a parameter).

Comment: @ADyson, thanks! I will check PHP, then, and I hope it solved my problems!

Comment: If the only reason for a backend is authentication then there is no need to use your own backend for that. you can use a service like https://auth0.com/ as your backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodeJs is not javascript, NodeJs is specific javascript "interpreter" whose is purpose is mainly to be executed server-side. If you have an HTML page, it is likely to be loaded in a web browser (client-side), so not in a NodeJs environnement.

Everything that is hard-coded in the javascript of you web page is visible from the client, there is no way around that. So yes, you need some server-ish thing somewhere.

If you are not to manage a server by yourself or via PaaS, you can go for a serverless architecture. For instance, If you consider AWS which I know the most, you can easilly add some user management to your web page using Aws Cognito User Pool. Once a user is connected and have the good permission, he can be granted access to some other resources via a JWT token that you send along with your request.

Comment: example here : https://medium.com/tensult/s3-direct-upload-with-cognito-authentication-56a5c0ff4916